# No logro obtener los datos del pago mediante IPN en Sandbox mode

Tags: java, mercadopago

Estoy teniendo un problema para probar las IPN en modo Sandbox.

Lo he probado de dos formas:

1. Mandándole la url_notification mediante preferences de pago. Cuando hago esto, me llama a mi url de notificación, pero cuando voy a buscar los datos del pago, ya sea mediante getPaymentInfo o haciendo un GET a https://api.mercadolibre.com/sandbox/collections/notifications/operation-ID?access_token=your_access_token (envíandole los parámetros necesarios), no obtengo resultado.
2. También probé quitándole la url_notification de la preference y configurándolo en mi cuenta de MercadoPago. Cuando lo hago de esta forma, ni siquiera llama a mi URL de notificación.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Creo que la URL es incorrecta, deberia ser https://api.mercadolibre.com/collections/ ... sin sandbox.

Comment: Creo que esa es la de producción, pero yo estoy probando en modo SandBox, por lo que entiendo que la URL es correcta.